# Session.cookies is empty while JavaScript document.cookie is not

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, window, electron

I want to get all the cookies from a BrowserWindow object, including HTTPonly cookies.
I've read through the documentation that the following code will output all the cookies being used in the BrowserWindow:
`windowObject.webContents.session.cookies`.
This returns an empty cookies object: `Cookies: {}`.

If I use the following code, I do get all the cookies except for the much needed HTTPonly (which are not returned due to security purposes):

```
return windowObject.webContents.executeJavaScript(`document.cookie;`,true).then(function(result){
 console.log(result);
});
```

**Proof of the issue;**
*Place this code inside your app.on('ready') function:*

```
const Window = electron.BrowserWindow;
var windowObject = new Window({show: true, webPreferences:{images:false}});
windowObject.loadURL("https://www.tweakers.net");
windowObject.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
  console.log(windowObject.webContents.session);
  console.log(windowObject.webContents.session.cookies);
  windowObject.webContents.executeJavaScript(`document.cookie;`, true).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

**Returns (this is truncated by me):**

[image: Truncated result from the commandline]
Why is it that the session returns no cookies? How can this be fixed?

I'm using Electron: `1.7.5`

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: @artgb Sorry that's not possible. I am however sure that at the moment I call ``session.cookies`` I also can receive the non HTTPonly cookies through ``executeJavaScript``. I will try to setup a script which will show the issue I have.

Comment: @artgb I've added proof of the issue to my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`windowObject.webContents.session.cookies` returns the defaultSession session object. Which put me on the wrong track of believing there was an unique `session` object tied to the `windowObject` object.

The cookies in my case could be retrieved through the following code:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const Window = electron.BrowserWindow;
var windowObject = new Window({show: true, webPreferences:{images:false}});
windowObject.loadURL("https://www.tweakers.net");
windowObject.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
  windowObject.webContents.session.cookies.get({}, (error, cookies) => {
    console.log(cookies);
  });
});
```

It is also possible to get all the cookies through the following code:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const session = electron.session;

return session.defaultSession.cookies.get({}, (error, cookies) => {
  console.log(cookies);
});
```

It is possible to filter on these to get the correct cookies belonging to a domain name for instance. To do this just simply use:

```
anySessionObject.cookies.get({domain: "yourdomain.com"}, (error, cookies) => {
  console.log(cookies);
});
```

A ticket about my findings has been opened on GitHub. You can view it here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10364